# Test fails, how to find out why?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to learn testing for angular using Jasmine and Karma, but I have runned into a bit of problem trying to create my first test.

First i got this very simple angular app with a controller named "testCtrl".

```
angular.module("testApp", [])
.controller("testCtrl", function() {
  this.title = "The Title";
});
```

I then got this very simple index.html file

```
<body data-ng-app="testApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="testCtrl as test">
    {{test.title}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Okay so this far everything works fine. The angular app is running.

Then we got my test.

```
describe("Testing AngularJS Test Suite", function() {
  describe("Testing AngularJS Controller", function() {

    it("should initialize the title in the scope", function() {
      module("testApp");

      var ctrl;

      inject(function($controller) {
        ctrl = $controller("testCtrl", {});
      });

      expect(ctrl.title).toBeDefined();
      expect(ctrl.title).toBe("The Title");
    });

  });

});
```

And then the karma configuration file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat Jun 04 2016 19:05:45 GMT+0200 (CEST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      '../../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      '../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../app.js',
      'units/*.js'
    ],
    proxies : {
      '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/'
    },    
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

And this it what I get when I then start karma.

```
04 06 2016 19:47:27.770:WARN [config]: "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
04 06 2016 19:47:28.165:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
04 06 2016 19:47:28.214:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
04 06 2016 19:47:28.248:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
04 06 2016 19:47:28.882:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#ulqwsz9WukaVrW-yAAAA with id 47817079
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Testing AngularJS Test Suite Testing AngularJS Controller should initialize the title in the scope FAILED
    some-parentfolders/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4631:53
    forEach@some-parentfolders/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:24
    loadModules@some-parentfolders/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4591:12
    createInjector@some-parentfolders/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4513:30
    workFn@some-parentfolders/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3060:60
    inject@some-parentfolders/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3040:46
    some-parentfolders/js/tests/units/testingAngularUnitSpec.js:9:13
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.049 secs / 0.038 secs)
```

Big note: This is a big angular application that requires a HTTP-server to run properly. Only this first test is simple. I was not sure if karma setup its own HTTP-server to run the files at or if it just used its HTTP-server for other stuff. And I read somewhere on the web the you should host the file on your own HTTP-server and then point the proxy in the karma config against that url to that server (as I have done above). Not sure about this so please correct me if I am wrong.

Since I dont get any specific error messages I am standing here clue less, and I was hoping someone could tell me what could be worng, where to look or how to start troubleshoting this.

Update:

After trying to run it with Chrome instead of PhantomJS I get these errors:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module some-parentfolders/js/tests due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'some-parentfolders/js/tests' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/nomod?p0=some-parentfolders/js/tests
```

But this dont make sense to me either?

Comment: Try to use Chrome instead. PhantomJS may swallow errors and be a PITA.

Comment: Will try and get back with updated error logs

Comment: I have added some new errors that Chrome gave me to my question. But these new errors dont make much sense to me either since the /tests folder is linked everyware it should be..

Comment: I was able to solve my issue just now, thanks to the new errors. @estus if you add your comment as a answer I will mark it as correct. Since what I was asking for was a way to move forward with my troubleshooting. :)

Comment: I don't consider it a real answer, but sure, Chrome worked for me with Karma where PhantomJS failed, and I wasn't the first person who noticed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS may be optimal for unit testing in some environments, but it tends to absorb error messages on some conditions, even with proper `logLevel`.

For better spec debugging, Chrome launcher may be used with Karma instead.