# AngularJS Unit tests broken after $httpBackend decorator

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, httpbackend

So I had a situation where we had to hit a "restful" service not under our control, where in order to get json back from the service on a GET call, we have to pass Content-Type="application/json" in the header. Only problem is that Angular strips the Content-Type from request headers on a GET.  I found a blog post that suggested using a decorator on $httpBackend that allows us to intercept the call before it is sent and add back the content type:

```
angular
.module('MyApp')
.decorator('$httpBackend', [
  '$delegate', function($delegate) {
      return function() {
          var contentType, headers;
          headers = arguments[4];
          contentType = headers != null ? headers['X-Force-Content-Type'] : null;
          if (contentType != null && headers['Content-Type'] == null)
            headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;

          return $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
      };
  }]);
```

so, that works beautifully! Now our problem is that it has broken all unit tests where we used the mock $httpBackend service. The only error we get is "undefined".

Ex. unit test method:

```
it('should return service.model.error if service returns an exception code from EndProject', 
 inject(function($httpBackend) {
      var mockResponse = sinon.stub({ 'exception': 'Unable to retrieve service data' });
      $httpBackend.whenPUT(this.endProjectUrl).respond(mockResponse);
      var data;
      this.service.EndProject().then(function(fetchedData) {
           data = fetchedData;
      });

      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(data.error.state).toBe(true);
      expect(data.error.message).toEqual('Unable to retrieve service data');
 }));
```

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) projectService EndProject should return service.model.error if service returns an exception code from EndProject FAILED
>       undefined
>       /Users/mlm1205/Documents/THDSource/bolt-projects/html_app/src/app/components/services/project/projectService.spec.js:213:41
>       invoke@/Users/mlm1205/Documents/THDSource/bolt-projects/html_app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4560:22
>       workFn@/Users/mlm1205/Documents/THDSource/bolt-projects/html_app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2518:26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I marked estus's answer as the solution, based purely on what my question was...in the end, ultimately it wasn't the end result we went with. In a case of not seeing the forest through the trees, the simplest solution was to add an empty data element to the $http call's config. I had tried it before and it didn't work (or so it seemed), but after playing with it again, it did in fact work and we were able to remove the decorator from the application.

```
return $http.get(getItemInformationUrl + params, { dataType: 'json', data: '', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }).then(getItemInformationCompleted).catch(getItemInformationFailed);
```

Answer (score 1):

The listed decorator covers simple monkey-patching scenario where patched function isn't a constructor and has no static properties and methods.

This is true for [`$httpBackend` in `ng` module](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.6/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L51), it is just a factory function with no extra properies.

This is not true for `ngMock` and `ngMockE2E` modules that override `$httpBackend` and have static methods, [at least some of them are documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#when).

This means that generally safe recipe (it doesn't cover non-enumerable and inherited properties) for monkey-patching a factory function is

```
app.decorator('$httpBackend', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    var $httpBackend = function () {
        ...
        return $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
    };
    angular.extend($httpBackend, $delegate);
    return $httpBackend;
}]);
```

Regardless of that, it is a good habit to modularize the app to the level where units can be tested in isolation with no excessive moving parts (this issue is an expressive example why this is important). It is convenient to have `app` (bootstrapped in production), `app.e2e` (bootstrapped in e2e tests), `app.common` (common denominator), `app.unitA` (loaded in `app.common` and can be loaded separately in unit test), etc.

Most of application-wide code (`config` and `run` blocks, routing) may be moved to separate modules and loaded only in modules that directly depend on them.  Unless this is a spec that tests `decorator` unit itself, decorator module shouldn't be loaded.

Also notice that [Chrome may offer superior experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37680331/3731501) than PhantomJS when debugging spec errors.

Comment: I tried that, but the call is still going out with the Content-Type stripped. I have an interceptor that injects another header that is needed by our load balancer, and had tried this for Content-Type but it didn't work. I debug through the interceptor code and verify that it does in fact add the header, but when you look at the actual call in the Network tab (Chrome dev tools), the Content-Type header is gone.

Comment: I guess I've misinterpreted your case before. You've got an existing decorator for production that works for you but fails in unit tests, despite the fact that unit tests don't make real requests. I've updated the answer. See the remark on PhantomJS, I'm quite sure that error message is crippled because of that and should say something like `undefined is not a function` due to `$httpBackend.whenPUT(...)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't make that clearer. I will try to play around a bit with what you suggested. I'm really trying to push back on the team that created the service to change it, because it's ridiculous to require that header on a GET request.